# How to change TabbedPage Icon when the tab is reselected in Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application using `Xamarin Forms` `TabbedPage` which has a feature that would allow the user to pause and play a page. Please see the code below.

**Shared Code**

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      var homePage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
      { 
         Title = "Home",
         Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_home_outline_25.png"
      };

      var phrasesPage = new NavigationPage(new PhrasesPage())
      {
         Title = "Play",
         Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25.png"
       };

       Children.Add(homePage);
       Children.Add(phrasesPage);
   }
}
```

**In iOS renderer:**

```
public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
   private MainPage _page;
   protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);
      var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;
      if (null != tabbarController)
      {
         tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabBarReselected;
       }
   }

   void OnTabBarReselected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs e)
   {
      var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
      var playTab = tabs.Children[4];

      if (TabBar.SelectedItem.Title == "Play") {
         if (tabs != null)
         {
            playTab.Title = "Pause";
            playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22.png";
         }
         App.pauseCard = false;
       }
       else {
        if (tabs != null) {
           playTab.Title = "Play";
           playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25.png";
       }
       App.pauseCard = true;
    }
}
```

**Android Renderer**

```
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer: TabbedPageRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
    {
       viewPager = (ViewPager)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
       tabLayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
       setup = true;

       ColorStateList colors = null;
       if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
       {
           colors = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab, Forms.Context.Theme);
       }
       else
       {
           colors = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab);
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.TabCount; i++)
       {
           var tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i);
           var icon = tab.Icon;
           if (icon != null)
           {
               icon = Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.Wrap(icon);
               Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.SetTintList(icon, colors);
           }
       }
   }

   void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
   {
      var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
      var playTab = tabs.Children[4];
      var selectedPosition = tab.Position;

      if(selectedPosition == 4) 
      {
         if (playTab.Title == "Play")
         {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
               playTab.Title = "Pause";
               playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22.png";
            }
            App.pauseCard = false;
          }
          else
          {
             if (tabs != null)
             {
                playTab.Title = "Play";
                playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25.png";
             }
             App.pauseCard = true;
           }
         }
    }
}
```

This is perfectly working in `iOS`. But somehow in `Android` only the `Title` would change but not the `Icon`. Anyone knows what Im missing or how it should be done? Also, is this possible to be done in the shared code instead of repeating almost exactly the same lines on code in each platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using the tab that is being passe to you in the `OnTabReselected` parameters in the `TabRenderer`.

You can move your whole logic with this object.

This is my whole renderer file (Android):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SWTabSelection.MainPage), typeof(SWTabSelection.Droid.MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace SWTabSelection.Droid
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private bool setup;

        public MyTabbedPageRenderer() { }

        public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            //Use this constructor for newest versions of XF saving the context parameter 
            // in a field so it can be used later replacing the Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context which is deprecated.
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
            {
                viewPager = (ViewPager)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
                setup = true;

                ColorStateList colors = GetTabColor();

                for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.TabCount; i++)
                {
                    var tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i);

                    SetTintColor(tab, colors);
                }
            }
        }


    void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {
        // To have the logic only on he tab on position 1
        if(tab == null || tab.Position != 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(tab.Text == "Play")
        {
            tab.SetText("Pause");
            tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_25);
            App.pauseCard = false;
        }
        else
        {
            tab.SetText("Play");
            tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25);
            App.pauseCard = true;
        }

        SetTintColor(tab, GetTabColor());

    }

        void SetTintColor(TabLayout.Tab tab, ColorStateList colors)
        {
            var icon = tab?.Icon;
            if(icon != null)
            {
                icon = Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.Wrap(icon);
                Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.SetTintList(icon, colors);            
            }
        }

        ColorStateList GetTabColor()
        {
            return ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23) 
                ? Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab, Forms.Context.Theme)
                               : Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab);
        }

    }
}
```

The only thing that I had with the code above is that the icon was not taking the Tint color so created a function with the same logic you had to set the Tint and I am using it on the Tab Reselection. If you have only one tab in your app you can set a global tint in the Android Theme/Style xml.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

`Custom Renderer` is no needed , you can change the `Title` and `Icon` directly in Shared code.

Just implement `CurrentPageChanged` event in `TabbedPage`

#### Complete code

```
public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
{
    NavigationPage homePage;
    NavigationPage phrasesPage;

    public TabbedPage1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var homePage = new NavigationPage(new Page1())
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Icon = "1.png"
        };

        var phrasesPage = new NavigationPage (new Page2())
        {
            Title = "Play",
            Icon = "1.png"
        };

        Children.Add(homePage);
        Children.Add(phrasesPage);

        this.CurrentPageChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

            var i = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                homePage.Title = "HomeChanged";
                homePage.Icon = "2.png";
            }
            else {
                phrasesPage.Title = "PlayChanged";
                phrasesPage.Icon = "2.png";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image]

PS: Make the image files access from a different platform.

iOS - `Resources`

Android - `Resources->drawable`

Comment: Thanks Cole. Sorry for the late reply, been busy lately. Will try your code later when I get home from work.

Comment: Hi Cole. I just read your comment again. I guess I wasnt so clear with my post. But I think I said "pause and play". So reselect the tab while on that same page. `CurrentPageChanged` would only be called when the page is changed.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to detect when a tab is reselected in Xamarin.Forms, so we'll have to use custom rederers to detect the logic.

For Android, we'll have to handle two cases: Current Tab Page Changed, and Current Tab Page Reselected.

We'll subscribe to to `CurrentPageChanged` and in its EventHandler, we'll check to see if the tab selected is `PhrasesPage`. If it is, we'll update the Icon/Text.

In `OnTabReselected`, we can check which page is currently selected, and if it's the `PhrasesPage`, we can update `PhrasesPage.Icon` and `PhrasesPage.Text`.

#### Sample App

https://github.com/brminnick/ChangeTabbedPageIconSample/tree/master

#### Android Custom Renderer

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(TabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        //Overloaded Constructor required for Xamarin.Forms v2.5+
        public TabbedPageRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Element.CurrentPageChanged += HandleCurrentPageChanged;
        }

        void HandleCurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var currentNavigationPage = Element.CurrentPage as NavigationPage;
            if (!(currentNavigationPage.RootPage is PhrasesPage))
                return;

            var tabLayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.TabCount; i++)
            {
                var currentTab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i);
                var currentTabText = currentTab.Text;

                if (currentTabText.Equals("Play") || currentTabText.Equals("Pause"))
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UpdateTab(currentTabText, currentTab, currentNavigationPage));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tab Reselected");

            var mainPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage;

            var currentNavigationPage = mainPage.CurrentPage as NavigationPage;

            if(currentNavigationPage.RootPage is PhrasesPage)
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UpdateTab(currentNavigationPage.Title, tab, currentNavigationPage));
        }

        void UpdateTab(string currentTabText, TabLayout.Tab tab, NavigationPage currentNavigationPage)
        {
            if (currentTabText.Equals("Puzzle"))
            {
                tab.SetIcon(IdFromTitle("Settings", ResourceManager.DrawableClass));
                currentNavigationPage.Title = "Settings";
            }
            else
            {
                tab.SetIcon(IdFromTitle("Puzzle", ResourceManager.DrawableClass));
                currentNavigationPage.Title = "Puzzle";
            }
        }

        int IdFromTitle(string title, Type type)
        {
            string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(title);
            int id = GetId(type, name);
            return id;
        }

        int GetId(Type type, string memberName)
        {
            object value = type.GetFields().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == memberName)?.GetValue(type)
                ?? type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == memberName)?.GetValue(type);
            if (value is int)
                return (int)value;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the custom render for tabbed page customization. For, Android you should refer the icon from Resource.Drawable. Please try with below code snippet in android renderer.

```cs
public class CustomTabRenderer: TabbedRenderer 
{
     private Activity _act;

     protected override void OnModelChanged(VisualElement oldModel, VisualElement newModel)
     {
         base.OnModelChanged(oldModel, newModel);

         _act = this.Context as Activity;
     }

     // You can do the below function anywhere.
     public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasWindowFocus)
     {   

         ActionBar actionBar = _act.ActionBar;

         if (actionBar.TabCount > 0)
         {
             Android.App.ActionBar.Tab tabOne = actionBar.GetTabAt(0);

            tabOne.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.shell);
         }
         base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
     }
 }
```

Refer this also: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17654/tabbedpage-icons-not-visible-android

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to `OnElementChanged` in `TabbedPageRenderer`

```
if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
{
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
    TabLayout layout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < layout.TabCount; i++)
    {
        var tab = layout.GetTabAt(i);
        var icon = tab.Icon;
        if (icon != null)
        {
            icon = Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.Wrap(icon);
            Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.SetTintList(icon, colors);
        }
    }
}
```

More info here : https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-android-selected-and-unselected-tab-colors/

Comment: Hi @Maverick, its not included in my code above but that lines of codes are already there. Please see the edited code above

Comment: You're also missing `base.OnElementChanged(e);` before `if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")`

Comment: Thanks. Added that. Didnt make any difference